# How to disable the items in the drop down list when an item is selected in other dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net

What I am trying to do is when the first dropdown is selected it would remove the selected item from the next dropdown. So, if you Have data: A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I in one dropdown if I select B in the first drop down then in the next dropdown it should only show A,C,D,E,F,G,H,I and so on up to 7 dropdowns. I dont know what would be the best way to approach this in asp.net??

Comment: but what you want to get from all 7 dropdowns??please put some light on that..i am not getting you want to disable item or remove that item in dropdown

Comment: I just want to disable that item from dropdownlist for the next event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the SelectedIndexChanged event of the DropDownList to determine when an Item has been selected and then iterate through the items in the other DropDownLists, removing the ones that you want. E.g.

```
void DropDownListOne_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
   ListItem selectedItem = DropDownListOne.SelectedItem;

   foreach(ListItem item in DropDownListTwo.Items)
   {
       if(item.Value == selectedItem.Value)
       {
           DropDownListTwo.Items.Remove(item);
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 ListItem item = d1.Items.FindByText(d1.SelectedValue);
 d2.Items.Remove(item);
```

If you have the characters as array, you can have

```
 string[] letters = new string[] {"A","B","C"};

 string d1SelValue = d1.SelectedValue;

 d2.DataSource = letters.Where(l => l != d1SelValue).ToArray();
 d2.DataBind();
```